# wsimport doesnt generate code related to soap headers

Tags: jaxb, wsimport

I'm generating client java code from a wsdl using 'wsimport'. The wsdl has soap:header in the operation definitions like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Test session web service methods.</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/">
      <s:element name="Logon">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="user" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="organisation" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="LogonResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LogonResult" type="tns:LogonResult" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:simpleType name="LogonResult">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="Ok" />
          <s:enumeration value="Error" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
      <s:element name="Header" type="tns:Header" />
      <s:complexType name="Header">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SessionID" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RunTask">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="argument" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="RunTaskResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RunTaskResult" type="tns:RunTaskResult" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:simpleType name="RunTaskResult">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="Ok" />
          <s:enumeration value="Error" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="LogonSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Logon" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="LogonSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LogonResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="LogonHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="Header" element="tns:Header" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RunTaskSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RunTask" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RunTaskSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RunTaskResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RunTaskHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="Header" element="tns:Header" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SessionSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Logon">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Logs on with the user credentials.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:LogonSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:LogonSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RunTask">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Runs a task.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RunTaskSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RunTaskSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SessionSoap" type="tns:SessionSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Logon">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.test.com/Logon" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:LogonHeader" part="Header" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RunTask">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.test.com/RunTask" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:RunTaskHeader" part="Header" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Session">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Test session web service methods.</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port name="SessionSoap" binding="tns:SessionSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://login.test.com/webservices/session.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This indicates that a request logon message would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <Logon xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
      <user>its_me</user>
      <password>its_my_pwd</password>
      <organisation>my_org</organisation>
    </Logon>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the response like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <Header xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
      <SessionID>ddffdf334-217d-41bb-9d7e-6289fefa8aaf</SessionID>
    </Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <LogonResponse xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
      <LogonResult>Ok</LogonResult>
    </LogonResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Yay, I found it myself. Adding the option '-XadditionalHeaders' to the wsimport command solved the problem. It generates an extra argument for the method through which the header can be passed/retrieved. I didn't delete the question because I was not able to find this solution on stack overflow and as such might be usefull

Comment: Thanks! .. ps: This is the top hit for "wsimport setting header" on google!

Answer (score 1):

I could not comment so I am writing this here as an "answer".

I ran into the same situation where there was only body in the envelope. However after adding the '-XadditionalHeaders' argument, wsimport still refused to generate service methods with header arguments. I searched on the Internet and found a manual patch in the following link:

https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/SOAP_headers.html

I did not do it in the code. Instead I changed the method signature of the web service operation method by adding arguments for the request header and annotating them with `@WebParam(header=true)`. I have not tested it with a real web service server, but at least the SOAP message now looks correct (no longer headless).

Answer (score 0):

-exsh (true/false)

Enables or disables processing of implicit SOAP headers (i.e. SOAP headers defined in the wsdl:binding but not wsdl:portType section.) Processing the SOAP headers requires the SOAP binding jars available on the classpath which was not the default in CXF 2.4.x and older. You may need to add a dependency to cxf-rt-binding-soap for this flag to work. Default is false.