# Adding custom HTTP headers to Axis 1.4 web service responses

Tags: java, web-services, axis, jax-rpc

I'm trying to add custom HTTP headers to Axis 1.4 web servers.

I've created a handler which extends BasicHandler:

```
public class HttpHeaderHandler extends BasicHandler {

  .
  .
  .

  @Override
  public void invoke(org.apache.axis.MessageContext arg0) throws AxisFault {  
    LOG.trace("invoke called");     
    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)ctx.getProperty(HTTPConstants.RESPONSE_HEADERS);
    if(ht == null) {
      ht = new Hashtable();
    }
    ht.put("custom-header", "Hello");
    ctx.setProperty(HTTPConstants.RESPONSE_HEADERS, ht);     
  }

  .
  .
  .

}
```

I've added the following to server-config.wsdd:

```
    .
    .
    .

<transport name="http">
    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="URLMapper" />
        <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler" />
    </requestFlow>
    <responseFlow>
        <handler type="java:com.my.package.HttpHeaderHandler" />
    </responseFlow>
</transport>

    .
    .
    .
```

I can see that the invoke method is being called as the logging is appearing in the log file but the custom header is not being added to the response.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution here in the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925272/handler-to-add-http-headers-to-http-request-not-invoked-when-using-axis-client-a.

Comment: I have provided you with an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do this on a `org.apache.axis.Stub` instance by doing the following:

```
private Stub setHeaders(Stub stub, Hashtable<String, String> headers){
    stub._setProperty(HTTPConstants.REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
    return stub;
}
```

Note that it is REQUIRED that the value argument to _setProperty() be a `java.util.Hashtable` (it gets cast later on by Axis when the Stub is used)

Answer (score 3):

I added apikey for request header thanks for @romeara answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787424/adding-custom-http-headers-to-axis-1-4-web-service-responses/33679569#33679569) . And it works.
Axis 1.4 sending client request from java.

```
YourStub stub = new YourStub();
Hashtable<String, String> headers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
headers.put("apikey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
stub._setProperty(HTTPConstants.REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

I remember using the stub files generated to add HTTP user and password, check this link and locate the code that says:

```
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/225102/Web-Services/java/Axis-username-password-auth-stubs

That kind of modification works.

Answer (score -1):

This is what we have done

```
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;

 /**
 * This method is to be used for secure SOAP calls.
 * Method created as Axis 1.4 strips the security header which compiling the Java classes.
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @return SOAP Header
 * @throws SOAPException
 */
public static SOAPHeaderElement createCustomSOAPHeader(String username, String password) throws SOAPException {
    SOAPHeaderElement oHeaderElement;
    SOAPElement oElement;   

    //Header
    oHeaderElement = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://siebel.com/webservices", "Security");
    oHeaderElement.setPrefix("web");
    oHeaderElement.setMustUnderstand(false);
    //Elements for the Header
    oElement = oHeaderElement.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
    oElement.addTextNode(username);
    oElement = oHeaderElement.addChildElement("PasswordText");
    oElement.addTextNode(password);
    oElement = oHeaderElement.addChildElement("SessionType");
    oElement.addTextNode("None");

    return oHeaderElement;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not HTTP Header, this is SOAP Header.

Comment: @MariuszS Isn't Axis 1.4 used for SOAP??? Can it be used for HTPP as well? Thats news to me.

Comment: Yes, Axis can be used for SOAP over HTTP Transport, and some real life scenerios requires adding http header. Look at this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925272/handler-to-add-http-headers-to-http-request-not-invoked-when-using-axis-client-a